# Data Studio Regex (Google RE2) to Extract Subdirectory from Path

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm working with a Google Data Studio field that has a page URL Path contained within it. Examples:

- **/**
- **/sample-url**
- **/sample-url-2**/
- **/#sample-url-5**/
- **/sample-url-3**/sample-url-4
- **/sample-url-3**/sample-url-6

In each one, I want to be capturing the bold portion in a custom formula/field--from the first slash, up to but excluding the second slash if there is one, and also including the first slash if that's the whole path. (In essence, the first subdirectory.) I would be open to recording the second backslash when there is one if that would make the solution simpler, but I'm guessing it's more complicated that way. I tried the following:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "^/[^/]+/$")
```

But it didn't work; everything returned null. What is wrong with that string?

Comment: Shorten your pattern to `^/[^/]*` without the last `/` and the anchor `$` See https://regex101.com/r/Hgh1Mj/1

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thefourthbird. Unfortunately, for some reason, it still seems to not be working--everything is coming back with null. Any other suggestions? Any chance this is a data studio issue? Thanks!

Comment: The pattern should work with the [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) syntax. Perhaps there is some whitespace before the first slash? `^\\s*/[^/]*` Did you use it like on [this page](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487?hl=en)?

Comment: It's so weird, still not getting anything. Yes, the formula should be exactly the same structure as the above hyperlinked page...I'm pulling a GA report, and this is my exact syntax: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, '^/[^/]*')` @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^/[^/]+/$` pattern matches a string that starts with a `/` char, then contains one or more chars other than `/` and then ends with a `/` char. So, you can only match strings like `/abc/`, `/123abc/`, `/abc-1 2 3.?!/`, etc.

You can use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "^(/[^/]*)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s7pjCu/1).

**NOTE**: `REGEXP_EXTRACT` requires a *capturing group* in the pattern, the content captured is the return value.

Here, `^` matches the start of string and `(/[^/]*)` is a *capturing group* with ID 1 that matches a `/` char and then any zero or more chars other than `/` (with `[^/]*`).

Comment: Sorry, I actually have one more question--what if I wanted to capture exclusively subdirectory 2? I figured out that by using the regex string ```"^(/[^/]*/[^/]*)"``` I get subdirectories 1 and 2 but I was hoping for just the second one, isolated... thanks!

Comment: @Lle.4 You can use `"^/[^/]+/([^/]*)"`